# ios webview crash

Tags: ios, webview, mobile-application, iphone-web-app

hi，i am a web developer and recently in the development of a Hybrid application.
My webpage base on zepto.js and iscroll ,when user ‘Pull up to load more’ the page send ajax request to get more items,the server will return package html , webpage just

```
$('#list').append(html)
```

the problem is when i load about 60-100 records ,the app will crash and exit.

ios developer told me every app have RAM  limit, maybe the webpage use up too much RAM....

i can't find the problem,someone give some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

if you dont have any memory leaks, and actually the total records is to much,

before crashing you will get the `didReceiveMemoryWarning`

so put this code in your view controller to check if thats the reason

```
 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     NSLog(@"too much for my memory!!");

}
```

if that is the reason, try to load less records and load them in batches?

;)